# VBox does not recognize USB devices

Tags: fedora, virtualbox, usb-device

Environment:

- Host: Fedora 32 kernel 5.9.15-100.fc32.x86_64
- Guest: Windows 10 Home Version 10.0.17134 Build 17134
- VBox 6.1.16
- VBoxGuestAdditions installed and mounted on W10 Guest
- USB settings - 1 filter with empty fields

I cannot see any USB devices.
I have tried to connect...

- 16 GB thumb drive
- Logitech Unifying Wireless mouse
- Line6 Helix LT Audio Device

... without success.

Comment: VirtualBox isn't all open-source: https://www.oracle.com/virtualization/technologies/vm/downloads/virtualbox-downloads.html#extpack

Comment: Using USB devices requires the non-free extension pack.

Comment: The extension pack is installed into VBox and mounted and executed on the guest.
See the "Environment" in my original post.

Comment: The "Guest Additions" is not the same as the "Extension Pack".  Please see https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads#VirtualBox6.1.16OracleVMVirtualBoxExtensionPack  Also see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/401427/vitualbox-not-detecting-my-usb-devices-with-a-linux-host and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/129305/how-can-i-enable-access-to-usb-devices-within-virtualbox-guests